# using std::stringstream as a the text that gets thrown as runtime error

Tags: c++

So basically, I am checking if a window is created in SDL and if not a runtime error is thrown. The following was suggested to me by someone in code review.

```
if (!windowCreated())
{
    std::stringstream buffer;
    buffer << "Could not intialize SDL properly: " << SDL_GetError();
}
```

But in line `std::stringstream buffer`, I get an error saying `incomplete type is not allowed`.

I was playing around with it and noticed that this error disappears if I do `std::stringstream buffer();`, but get a new error saying `expression must have integral or unscoped enum type` in the next line.

The following function shows what I am trying to achieve.

```
void throwError()
{
    bool windowCreated = false;
    if (!windowCreated)
    {
        const char* SDL_ERROR = "someerrror";
        std::stringstream buffer;
        buffer << "error: " << SDL_ERROR;
        throw std::runtime_error(buffer.str());
    }
}
```

Comment: If you open your C++ textbook to the chapter that explains how to use `std::stringstream`, it'll tell you which header needs to get `#include`d in order to use it. That should solve this compilation error. P.S. this is compilation error, and not a runtime error.

Comment: `bool windowCreated = false; if (!windowCreated)` - what is purpose of this?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Thank you. It worked

Comment: fwiw, `std::stringstream buffer();` declares `buffer` as a function that returns a `std::stringstream`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have `#include <sstream>` in your code in order to use `std::stringstream` (in your case, prefer `std::ostringstream` instead). You are likely missing that header file include, but the class has been *forward-declared* in another header file that you are including. That would explain why the compiler thinks the class is an incomplete type.

The reason why `std::stringstream buffer();` doesn’t work is because that is not a declaration for a `std::stringstream` variable named `buffer`, but rather is  a declaration for a function named `buffer` that takes no arguments and returns a `std::stringstream`.